# No method error in contact form for Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm putting a contact form together using the following tutorial: http://matharvard.ca/posts/2011/aug/22/contact-form-in-rails-3/

I've followed all the instructions, but for some reason I keep getting this error when I try to access the Contact page in my app:

```
NoMethodError in Contact#new

undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #1):

1: <%= form_for @message, :url => contact_path do |form| %>
2:   <fieldset class="fields">
3:     <div class="field">
4:       <%= form.label :name %>
```

What am I missing here?

**new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @message, :url => contact_path do |form| %>
<fieldset class="fields">
<div class="field">
  <%= form.label :name %>
  <%= form.text_field :name %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= form.label :email %>
  <%= form.text_field :email %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= form.label :subject %>
  <%= form.text_field :subject %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= form.label :body %>
  <%= form.text_area :body %>
</div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="actions">
<%= form.submit "Send" %>
</fieldset>
<% end %>
```

**contact_controller.rb**

```
class ContactController < ApplicationController

def new
  @message = Message.new
end

def create
  @message = Message.new(params[:message])

if @message.valid?
  NotificationsMailer.new_message(@message).deliver
  redirect_to(root_path, :notice => "Message was successfully sent.")
else
  flash.now.alert = "Please fill all fields."
  render :new
end
end
end
```

**notifications_mailer.rb**

```
class NotificationsMailer < ActionMailer::Base

default :from => "myemail@gmail.com"
default :to => "myemail@gmail.com"

def new_message(message)
  @message = message
  mail(:subject => "[myemail@gmail.com] #{message.subject}")
end
end
```

Comment: Did you set up your routes correctly?

Comment: yeah, the routes are definitely good. any other ideas?

Comment: I see 2 possibilities. Either there is a problem with your Message model, or you should maybe restart the server.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with this tutorial. It was because I forgot to remove `< ActiveRecord::Base` from the Message class. I also forgot to change `attr_accessible` to `attr_accessor`. You may want to double check those two points.